# How to rotate proxies and user agents

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I am writing a Scrapy program and I login and scrape data for different playing cards on this website,http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/.  But I only scrape ID values from this url and then I redirect to a different URL using that ID number and scrape that JSON webpage and do that for all 207 different categories of cards.  I looks a little more authentic then just going straight to URL with the JSON data.  Anyways I have written Scrapy program before with multiple URLs and I am able to set those programs up to rotate proxies and user agents, but how would I do it in this program?  Since there is technically only one URL, like is there a way to set it up to switch to a different proxy and user agent after it scrapes like 5 or so different JSON data pages? I do not want it to rotate randomly.  I would like it to scrape the same JSON webpage with the same proxy and user agent each time.  I hope that all makes sense.  This might be a little broad for stack overflow but I have no idea how to do this so I figured I would ask anyways to see if anyone has any good ideas on how to do this.

```
# Import needed functions and call needed python files
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from ..items import DataItem

# Spider class
class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Name of spider
    name = "LoginSpider"

    #URL where dated is located
    start_urls = ["http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/"]

    # Login function
    def parse(self, response):
        # Login using email and password than proceed to after_login function
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formcss='#existing_users form',
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'example@email.com', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
        )


    # Function to barse buylist website
    def after_login(self, response):
        # Loop through website and get all the ID numbers for each category of card and plug into the end of the below
        # URL then go to parse data function
        for category_id in response.xpath('//select[@id="bl-category-options"]/option/@value').getall():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                    url="http://www.starcitygames.com/buylist/search?search-type=category&id={category_id}".format(category_id=category_id),
                    callback=self.parse_data,
                    )
    # Function to parse JSON dasta
    def parse_data(self, response):
        # Declare variables
        jsonreponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        # Call DataItem class from items.py
        items = DataItem()

        # Scrape category name
        items['Category'] = jsonreponse['search']
        # Loop where other data is located
        for result in jsonreponse['results']:
            # Inside this loop, run through loop until all data is scraped
            for index in range(len(result)):
                # Scrape the rest of needed data
                items['Card_Name'] = result[index]['name']
                items['Condition'] = result[index]['condition']
                items['Rarity'] = result[index]['rarity']
                items['Foil'] = result[index]['foil']
                items['Language'] = result[index]['language']
                items['Buy_Price'] = result[index]['price']
                # Return all data
                yield items
```

Comment: If you don't want to always go and check for available free proxies, you can use this library https://github.com/nabinkhadka/scrapy-rotating-free-proxies. While running a spider, this library will automatically fetch fresh and newly available proxies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will recomend this package for you 
[Scrapy-UserAgents](https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy-UserAgents/)

```
pip install scrapy-useragents
```

In your setting.py file

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
'scrapy_useragents.downloadermiddlewares.useragents.UserAgentsMiddleware': 500,
```

}

### User Agents example List to rotate

[More User Agents](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/)

```
USER_AGENTS = [
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/57.0.2987.110 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/61.0.3163.79 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) '
     'Gecko/20100101 '
     'Firefox/55.0'),  # firefox
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/61.0.3163.91 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/62.0.3202.89 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/63.0.3239.108 '
     'Safari/537.36'),  # chrome
]
```

Be careful this middleware can’t handle the situation that the COOKIES_ENABLED is True, and the website binds the cookies with User-Agent, it may cause unpredictable result of the spider.

Comment: the best and simple  solution. upvoted

Answer (score 2):

**Proxies**
I would get a company that offers a rotator so you don't have to mess with that however you could write a custom middleware I will show you how. What you want to do is edit the process request method. You would do this both for changing the proxy and also for changing the user agent.

**UserAgents**
You can use Scrapy random user agent middleware https://github.com/cleocn/scrapy-random-useragent or this is how you can change whatever you want about the request object using a middleware including the proxies or any other headers.

```
# middlewares.py

user_agents = ['agent1', 'agent2', 'agent3', 'agent4']
proxies = ['ip1:port1', 'ip2:port2', 'ip3:port3', 'ip4:port4'

# either have your user agents in a file or something this assumes you are able to get them into a list.

class MyMiddleware(object):
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Called for each request that goes through the downloader
        # middleware.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this request
        # - or return a Response object
        # - or return a Request object
        # - or raise IgnoreRequest: process_exception() methods of
        #   installed downloader middleware will be called
        request.headers['User-Agent'] = random.choice(user_agents) # !! These 2 lines
        request.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(proxies) # !! These 2 lines
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # Called with the response returned from the downloader.

        # Must either;
        # - return a Response object
        # - return a Request object
        # - or raise IgnoreRequest
        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        # Called when a download handler or a process_request()
        # (from other downloader middleware) raises an exception.

        # Must either:
        # - return None: continue processing this exception
        # - return a Response object: stops process_exception() chain
        # - return a Request object: stops process_exception() chain
        pass

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)

# settings.py


DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'project.middlewares.MyMiddleware': 543,
}
```

References:
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html

Comment: I have a proxy list which contains ip:port:username:password, how do I add these 4 parameters in my request

Answer (score 1):

USERAGENTS : 
I have used this tool which will keep your list of user-agents always updated with most recent and most used user-agents : 
https://pypi.org/project/shadow-useragent/

```py
    from shadow_useragent import ShadowUserAgent
    shadow_useragent = ShadowUserAgent()

     print(shadow_useragent.firefox)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
     print(shadow_useragent.chrome)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36
     print(shadow_useragent.safari)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15
     print(shadow_useragent.edge)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.140 Safari/537.36 Edge/17.17134
     print(shadow_useragent.ie)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
     print(shadow_useragent.android)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; en-us; SM-N900T Build/JSS15J) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
     print(shadow_useragent.ipad)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
     print(shadow_useragent.random)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0

     print(shadow_useragent.random_nomobile)
     # Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36

    # and the best one, random via real world browser usage statistic
    print(ua.random)
    # Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36

    # if you want to excluse mobiles (some websites will display different pages)
    print(shadow_useragent.random_nomobile)
    # Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.90 Safari/537.36
```