# How do I get rid of an error when trying to scrape a site?

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I try to scrape woolworths for grocery price data, I get the following error: *urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden*

Here's what my code looks like:

```
    session = requests.session()
url = "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/fruit-veg"
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}
req = session.get(url, headers = headers)
fruitAndVeg = BeautifulSoup(req.text)
```

---

I searched it up and changed my headers, but it still isn't working after that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a complete user-agent such as

```
headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) FxiOS/96.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1.15"}
```

Additionally, it may so happen that some websites in the loop might not be simply available, to cater to it. You must catch the statement in a python exception to prevent breaking the code.

If this does not work, try using rotating proxy by using a more robust scrapping platform `Scrapy`
[How to rotate proxies and user agents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889999/how-to-rotate-proxies-and-user-agents)